# How to sort an array with duplicate values using Array.prototype.sort()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, duplicates

I want to sort an array with duplicate values using the [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

For instance if I execute this `[1, 2, 0, 1].sort((a, b) => a + b)` to achieve a sorted array in descending order, I am returned back the same array `[1, 2, 0, 1]`.

Why is this happening and how can I sort this array using `Array.prototype.sort`? Is javascript's Array sort not reliable for sorting through duplicate values or am I providing a function that isn't making the right comparisons? I would like to achieve this using `Array.prototype.sort` and not have to write my own sort function.

Thanks!

Comment: `.sort((a, b) => a - b)` maybe. And `sort` does not return a new array. It mutates the existing array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to subtract the two values.

```js
//ascending order
console.log([1, 2, 0, 1].sort((a, b) => a - b))

//descending order
console.log([1, 2, 0, 1].sort((a, b) => b - a))
```

Answer (score 0):

The Reason, why it is not working is:

If you look into [offical MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort),

> The sort() method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns
>   the array. The default sort order is built upon converting the
>   elements into strings, then it compairs the array.

```js
var months = ['March', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Dec'];
months.sort();
console.log(months);
// expected output: Array ["Dec", "Feb", "Jan", "March"]

var array1 = [1, 2, 0, 1];
array1.sort((a, b) => a + b);
console.log(array1);
// expected output: Array [1, 2, 0 ,1]
```

> So, To compare numbers instead of strings, the compare function can
>   simply subtract b from a. The following function will sort the array
>   ascending (if it doesn't contain Infinity and NaN)

```js
function compareNumbers(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}
```